# How to use svg in Angular2

Tags: angular, svg

I have an object in the form svg. How to use it with Angular2? How use the ngclass in path?

```
<div *ngIf="isSelect(false); else noSelectUpVote">
    <a>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 29 15" width="29" height="15">
            <g>
                <path class="vote-select" d="M0 15h29l-14.5-15" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </a>
</div>
<ng-template #noSelectUpVote>
    <a>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 29 15" width="29" height="15">
            <g>
                <path class="vote-no-select" d="M0 15h29l-14.5-15" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </a>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: What's the problem? What are you trying to accomplish? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I do not want to duplicate the code. SVG is copied, and only class in path changes.

Comment: Still no idea what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ngClass` like that

`[ngClass]="{'style1': isClass1Visible, 'style2': isClass2Visible}"`

Comment: If you required IE10+ support, you can add Polyfill to support ngClass on SVG "https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js"

Comment: In angular-cli, check `polyfills.ts` for `classlist.js`.